# Understanding the change-of-coordinate matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know that if you have a linear transformation $T:V \rightarrow W$ where $V,W$ are finite-dimensional then there is a matrix $A \in M_{m \times n}(\mathbb F)$ that represents $T$ (not sure if that's the correct wording), but I mean for all $x\in V$, $Ax=Tx$.

I understand this idea, but I don't fully understand how the change-of-coordinate matrix comes into this. Does it mean if we change the basis, then the representation of $T$ as $A$ must also change?

If anyone can help clarify this, that would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your statement is not quite correct. Since $T:V \to W$, this means that for any $v \in V$, you have some associated value $Tv \in W$.

Now suppose $v_1,...,v_n$ is an ordered basis for $V$ and $w_1,...,w_m$ is an ordered basis for $W$. Then any $v \in V$ can be uniquely represented by $ v = \sum_i x_i v_i$, where $x_i$ are scalars (that is, $x \in \mathbb{F}^n$).

That is, there is an association between any $v\in V$ and a correspinding $ x \in \mathbb{F}^n$. But $v$ and $x$ 'live' in different spaces
(unless $V = \mathbb{F}^n$ with the corresponding ordering.)

Similarly, any $w \in W$ can be uniquely represented by $ w = \sum_i y_i w_i$, where $y_i$ are scalars (that is, $y \in \mathbb{F}^m$).

If we use the above bases to represent $T$ with a matrix $A: \mathbb{F}^n \to \mathbb{F}^m$, then if $Tv = w$, with  $v = \sum_i x_i v_i$ and $ w = \sum_i y_i w_i$, then $A x = y$.

And similarly, if $Ax = y$, this means $T(\sum_i x_i v_i) = \sum_i y_i w_i$.

Comment: So $A$ would change the scalar elements?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking. $A$ operates on the $\mathbb{F}^n$ representation of $v$ to get some $y \in \mathbb{F}^m$ which is the representation of $Tv$ .

Comment: Okay, I think I see what you mean. Thank you. So would $[T]_\beta$ mean the representation of $T$ with respect to the basis $\beta$?

Comment: There are various notations, but yes, I imagine that $A=[T]_\beta$ in that notation (usually there is a notation for the domain and range bases, not just one basis).

Comment: You mean $[T]_\beta^\gamma$? What would be the interpretation of this?

Comment: It means the matrix of the transformation $T$ using the ordered basis $\beta$ for the domain and the ordered basis $\gamma$ for the range.

Comment: Thank you for all your help!

Comment: You are very welcome.